# actualizar registros desde listview android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crud

Tengo una lista donde me aparecen todos los registros insertados.
Cuando los inserto, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
 ` Motorista mt= new Motorista();
                mt.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                mt.setNombre(nombre);
                mt.setMoto(moto);
                databaseReference.child("Motorista").child(mt.getId()).setValue(mt);
                Toast.makeText(this,"Añadir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Como se puede apreciar, el id se introduce aleatoriamente.
Cuando quiero actualizar, hago click encima del registro para dirigirme a otro activity con los datos recogidos:

```
case R.id.update:{
            lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    mtSeleccionado = (Motorista) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    String id= mtSeleccionado.getId();
                    String x= mtSeleccionado.getNombre();
                    String y= mtSeleccionado.getMoto();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, formularioActualizar.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", id);
                    intent.putExtra("nombre", x);
                    intent.putExtra("moto", y);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Aquí ya estoy en el activity de actualización. Los campos aparecen rellenos con los datos correspondientes:

```
        Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b!=null){
        id=b.getString("id");
        nombre=b.getString("nombre");
        moto=b.getString("moto");
    }

    nombre_actualizar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombreActualizar);
    moto_actualizar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.motoActualizar);
    boton_confirmar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_confirmar);

    nombre_actualizar.setText(nombre);
    moto_actualizar.setText(moto);

    boton_confirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Motorista mt= new Motorista();
            mt.setId(id);
            mt.setNombre(nombre);
            mt.setMoto(moto);
            databaseReference.child("Motorista").child(mt.getId()).setValue(mt);

        }
    });
```

El problema es que al hacer click en el botón confirmar, se me cierra la aplicación. No sé si el problema está en el paso del id o al haber creado un DatabaseReference igual que el que tengo en el MainActivity...

Comment: Cual es el problema que arroja el logcat?

Comment: 2019-02-26 10:39:22.267 5895-5895/com.jorgegcano.firebaseapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jorgegcano.firebaseapp, PID: 5895
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.jorgegcano.firebaseapp.formularioActualizar$1.onClick(formularioActualizar.java:50)
        
---------------------->LA LÍNEA DEL ERROR ES ESTA: databaseReference.child("Motorista").child(mt.getId()).setValue(mt);

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa @Gastón Saillén. Soy novato y no había caído en comprobar el error mediante el logcat. Al comprobarlo he podido averiguar la solución. Muchísimas gracias.
El problema estaba en la siguiente línea:

```
databaseReference.child("Motorista").child(mt.getId()).setValue(mt);
```

Estaba creando un id de un motorista con el resto de parámetros vacíos. La solución es llamar a un registro ya insertado solicitando su id.

El procedimiento sería el siguiente.

Creación de un motorista:

```
Motorista mt= new Motorista();
                    mt.setId(databaseReference.push().getKey()); //También podríamos crear el id así, de forma aleatoria. mt.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); 
                    mt.setNombre(nombre);
                    mt.setMoto(moto);
                    databaseReference.child("Motorista").child(mt.getId()).setValue(mt);
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Añadir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    nombreEt.setText(" ");
                    motoEt.setText(" ");
```

Llamada al método update:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        mtSeleccionado = (Motorista) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, formularioActualizar.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", mtSeleccionado.getId()); //databaseReference.push().getKey()
                        intent.putExtra("nombre", mtSeleccionado.getNombre());
                        intent.putExtra("moto", mtSeleccionado.getMoto());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

recuperación de parámetros:

```
Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b!=null){
        id=b.getString("id");
        nombre=b.getString("nombre");
        moto=b.getString("moto");
    }
```

Declaración de los campos de texto del formulario de actualización:

```
nombre_actualizar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombreActualizar);
        moto_actualizar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.motoActualizar);
        boton_confirmar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_confirmar);
```

Rellenamos estos campos con los datos recogidos en el bundle:

```
nombre_actualizar.setText(nombre);
    moto_actualizar.setText(moto);
```

Y actualizamos con el siguiente método:

```
            boton_confirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//declaración de la variable DatabaseReference llamando a una referencia que ya tenemos guardada solicitando su id:
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Motorista").child(id);
//los parámetros de este motorista podrían estar vacíos. Los he metido para comprobar que los recibía correctamente.
                Motorista mt= new Motorista(id, nombre, moto);
//con este print compruebo que el motorista recibido es el correcto.
                System.out.println(mt);
//insertamos los parámetros que hemos modificado. El id se queda igual, evidentemente:
                mt.setId(id);
                mt.setNombre(nombre_actualizar.getText().toString());
                mt.setMoto(moto_actualizar.getText().toString());
//comprobamos que se han modificado:
                System.out.println(mt);
//Insertamos el registro modificado:
                databaseReference.setValue(mt);
//volvemos al menú principal:
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Genial que lo hayas encontrado :)

Answer (score 0):

Tu respuesta esta excelente, una sugerencia es colocar la declaracion de tu `DatabaseReference` dentro de tu `onCreate()` para que asi tengas una sola instancia al iniciar esa actividad y no crees una instancia cada vez que oprimes el boton

Declaramos globalmente para acceder a la referencia

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
```

dentro de tu onCreate()

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Motorista").child(id);
```

Luego tu boton quedaria de la siguiente forma

```
 boton_confirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//declaración de la variable DatabaseReference llamando a una referencia que ya tenemos guardada solicitando su id:

//los parámetros de este motorista podrían estar vacíos. Los he metido para comprobar que los recibía correctamente.
                Motorista mt= new Motorista(id, nombre, moto);
//con este print compruebo que el motorista recibido es el correcto.
                System.out.println(mt);
//insertamos los parámetros que hemos modificado. El id se queda igual, evidentemente:
                mt.setId(id);
                mt.setNombre(nombre_actualizar.getText().toString());
                mt.setMoto(moto_actualizar.getText().toString());
//comprobamos que se han modificado:
                System.out.println(mt);
//Insertamos el registro modificado:
                databaseReference.setValue(mt);
//volvemos al menú principal:
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```